# how to display the volume name automatically on windows/linux

Tags: windows, embedded, usb, libusb, usb-drive

I am writing a USB driver to a product which is basically a USB pen drive. Upon connecting the product to the usb port, I want to see the drive name/volume name as "XXXX Corporation". I see that by default it always gets shown as "Removable Disk" in Windows explorer or my computer. 
If I use any  USB detail reader tools available in the net, then I can see the vendor id and manufacturer ids and other usb details. Renaming the drive from windows works but I want this to happen by default without asking the end user to rename. Having autorun.inf in root of the drive works only on WindowsXP. 
How do I get this? Are there any descriptors which needs to be coded explicitly in my usb drivers stack? There are already API's to obtain the manufacturer/Product/Serial descriptors in my usb drivers stack.

Thanks in advance.

Chandra

Answer (score 1):

The name shown in file explorers is the filesystem label, it's not a USB descriptor. The tool you are using to create the filesystem (whether FAT or NTFS) probably allows you to set the label. It can also be changed on an existing filesystem. The label can also be read on any operating system.

The `label` entry of the [autorun.inf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144200%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) file should also be read by modern Windows. *Some* Linux file explorers (Gnome's Nautilus) might use it if it's there, but the cross-platform way is the filesystem label.

Comment: Hi Leiaz, Thanks for the answer. Actually in our product, we were using a SD card for storage and this was interfacing to PC via USB. I could figure out that in the sd card map, there is something called as Volume Label, which had to be changed to get whatever volume label we want to see when connected to PC.